# RouterLinks Issue in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

How can i resolve this routerLink issue? Is there something i am not doing right in the page.ts?

**dashboard routes**

```
{path:'ticket', component: ComposeEmailComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard],

          children:[
                {
                    path:'openticket', component:OpenTicketComponent
                },

                {
                    path:'chat/:id', component: AgentChatPageComponent
                }



                ]

  },
```

**page.html**

```
//this routes to the page i want to go

      <a class="btn btn-success " title="Chat" [routerLink]="['../chat', Page.id]" ><em class="fa fa-whatsapp"></em></a>
```

**page.ts**

```
//this line gives an error that the route doesn't match any routes.

    this.router.navigate(['../chat', Page.id]);
```

**ActivatedRoute**

```
constructor(private httpService:HttpService, private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router ){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicitly say that you current route navigation should be [`relativeTo`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html) current Activated route (as you have `../` in route), by specifying `{ relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }` in `router.navigate` function.

```
//make sure you injected ActivatedRoute dependency before using it in `navigate` function.
this.parentRouter.navigate(['../chat', Page.id], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
```

Comment: i get this error thrown `'chat/4;relativeTo=Route(url%3A'openticket'%2C%20path%3A'openticket')'`

Comment: @Amateur did you injected `ActivatedRoute` dependency correctly ??

Comment: Just like how i have updated my question.. That's how i injected it

Comment: @Amateur Check updated answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: @yurzui Hey mate, thanks for added that missing `]` closing brackets. Thanks a lot :)